# Yii2.0 installation is not working using composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

**composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic**
The following is the ouput of above command

```
Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (2.0.6)  
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-basic (2.0.6)  
    Loading from cache  
Created project in basic 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.5, 2.0.6].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Comment: Did you install fxp composer asset plugin ? `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`

Comment: @soju yes i just installed and its working. Thanx for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, refer the [installation guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic#install-via-composer). It seems that you are missing asset plugin:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.2.0"
```

Comment: Yes i just installed fxp composer and its working. Thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should run `composer clear-cache` first before running

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

This worked for me.